# Can we use variables in Siddhi SQL statements?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I'm going to use the same value in lots of statements in the SQL Expression. So it is possible to declare and assign the value to a variable at the beginning of the query and refer the value by it?
(I'm writing an execution plan in WSO2 DAS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported as of now. However, supporting this has been under discussion, hence this might be implemented in a future release.

If you want to  store a value and use it in a query, the currently available ways are:

- Putting that value into an [indexed event table](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0#SiddhiQLGuide3.0-IndexingEventTable) and then doing a join with the event table to read that value whenever required.

Indexed In-memory Event Table internally uses a Hash-Map, therefore you could use one to store your variables, in such a way that the key of the hashmap will be the name of your varaible and the value of the hashmap will be the value of your variable.

However I feel that above solution is too complicated for your requirement.

- Using the [Map Extension in Siddhi](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53120281)

Comment: @PasinduJw I am currently using Siddhi QL, and i have a strange requirement. Input data is given in quote e.g. "apple" and the output would be : apple.
I have tried using 
select 
substr(sensorId,1,4) as out 
insert into outputStream;


Than i am getting error "substr is neither a function nor an aggregated attribute, "

HOwever i have tried using JS to substring it and i got :

jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:1:22 Missing space after numeric literal
var data = [""tempID=1wef"",0]

do you have any alternative solution ; or am i doing something wrong

Comment: The proper way to use substr function in siddhi is as follows: select str:substr(sensorId,1,4) as partOfString. You may use replaceAll function as well.